# Values not getting incremented, using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to perform a formula in Android Studio that increments it's past value, however instead of incrementing the last value it replaces the last value with the new value. This is the formula:

```
                    insCalories += (insValue * nutritional_Cal) /100;
                    insProtein += (insValue * nutritional_Pro) /100;
                    insFats += (insValue * nutritional_Fat) /100;
                    insCarbs += (insValue * nutritional_Car) /100;
```

(the formula is performed every time the user clicks on a certain button)

But the formula is, at least displaying in TextViews, as if it was set up like this:

```
                    insCalories = (insValue * nutritional_Cal) /100;
                    insProtein = (insValue * nutritional_Pro) /100;
                    insFats = (insValue * nutritional_Fat) /100;
                    insCarbs = (insValue * nutritional_Car) /100;
```

I have also tried to change this to inCalories += 5 to see if perhaps something was wrong with the formula itself, however the TextViews which show the insCalories, insProtein etc. Still display the data as if the formula was insCalories = 5.

So I think that I might be doing something wrong using SharedPreferences, I can however not find any mistake there either.

Every time the user clicks on the button, the formulas are executed and I use my save() method to store the new values in SharedPreferences. This is what it does:

```
        public final void save() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("Calories", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(insCalories));
        editor.putLong("Protein", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(insProtein));
        editor.putLong("Fats", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(insFats));
        editor.putLong("Carbs", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(insCarbs));

        editor.apply();

}
```

Then when the user navigates to the activity where the data is displayed, I use methods in OnCreateView to retrieve the new values and set them to display in TextViews:

```
double SPCalories;
double SPProtein;
double SPFats;
double SPCarbs;

String dc_text;
String dp_text;
String d_cartext;
String df_text;

TextView Calories_text;
TextView protein_text;
TextView carbs_text;
TextView fats_text;

Context CTX;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daily_intake, container, false);

    Calories_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Calories_text);

    protein_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.protein_text);

    carbs_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.carbs_text);

    fats_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fats_text);

    CTX = getContext();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SPCalories = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Calories", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPProtein = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Protein", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPFats = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Fats", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPCarbs = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Carbs", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));

    DecimalFormat db = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    db.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

    dc_text = db.format(SPCalories);
    dp_text = db.format(SPProtein);
    d_cartext = db.format(SPCarbs);
    df_text = db.format(SPFats);


    Calories_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Calories), dc_text));
    protein_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Protein), dp_text));
    carbs_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Carbs), d_cartext));
    fats_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Fats), df_text));
```

Please tell me if you have any clue as to what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Vidal

Comment: The display part seems all fine, but the increment part of your code is mostly missing from this question. Most likely your `insX` variables get reinstantiated every time while you expect them to persist, but it is impossible to tell from the information given.

Comment: Where is the button press event?